# change color list item's value when a button is pressed

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, themes

In my android app text colors of buttons are defined in a "color state list " xml file called buttoncolor.xml
what I'm tryin to do is to change the theme of the app from green to blue with a click of button 
so when the user clicks,color value of the buttoncolor.xml file changes from green ("#4CD964") to blue ...forever (it doesn't matter if it's done from xml or java)

Here's my code

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:color="#4CD964"
            android:state_pressed = "true"
        />
        <item
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />
    </selector>
```

How can I Achieve this ?

Comment: have You set the selector as background for Your button?

Comment: Let's just assume I intend to change the text colors with the theme change ...
But Yes I have a Selector file for my backgrounds in drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the XML. When an activity loads, use a ThemeSettings object with SharedPreferences to set your button drawable based on your user preference. You need an XML for each drawable option.